# Calling a function from another file in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to call the function handleText from another file.

```
package
{   
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public function handleText(mc:MovieClip):void
    {
        mc.text="aaaaaa";
    }
}
```

But when I call the function handleText from another file (which is in the same directory as the file with the above code, also with "package {" on top), I get an error of undefined function. What is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You need to create a class first, then create an instance of that class, I think you need to go away and read up on Object Oriented Programming first.. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/oop_as3.html

Comment: I know OOP. Is AS3 completely object oriented, not supporting global functions whatsoever?

Comment: Sorry I presumed you didn't know OOP! AS3 is Object Oriented yes, you need to supply a Document Class if you are using the Flash IDE, then you can have a bunch of global functions if that's what you want.

Comment: Can I just spread class methods across a few files (and by so have handleText be a method of the other class I'm using)? How can I do that?

Comment: OK that's where you need to create instances of classes and call methods from those classes, please have a read of the link I posted above, it explains it pretty well for AS3

Comment: I don't need a refresh of basic concepts of OOP, I just need to know if I can (and how can I) split implementation of a class to a few files

Comment: No you can't have one class split over multiple files in AS3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about something like Categories in Objective-C where developers are able to add functionality to a class in a separate file without needing to modify the original class code? If so, then no. Since classes and their structure in AS3 is heavily connected to the file structure, there is no way to extend the functionality in already defined classes in separate files.

However, you can add/modify functionality of classes using inheritance. That way you can add, for example, methods and variables in separate .as files, but the new class will be treated as a separate class with its own name.